# Using command-line to pack files individually into .zip format while keeping directory structure

Tags: command-line, zip, cmd.exe

I'm trying to create a `cmd` script that recursively traverses a directory and zip each file individually. This I have done here:

```
for /R %%b IN (*.*) do ( "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a "%%~nb.zip" "%%b" )
```

However, I would like to keep the zip files in the original folder structure and have the results be in a separate folder than the original folder. For example:

**Before:**

```
/original
    /some_files
        file-1.txt
        file-2.txt
```

**After:**

```
/original
    /some_files
        file-1.txt
        file-2.txt

/packed
    /some_files
        file-1.zip
        file-2.zip
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to alter the original?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out something close:

```
for /R %%b IN (*.*) do ("C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ibck "%%~pb\%%~nb.zip" "%%b" )
```

It creates the zips in the directories they come in. I could add the proper path before `%%~pb` but it currently pulls the full path "C:\Users\Matt..." so I probably need something different there.

`-ibck` keeps WinRAR running in the background.

This was good enough to solve my problem though.